# lapply For Multiple Files

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

```
BorderData07 <- read_csv("Downloads/BorderData/BorderApprehension2007.csv")
BorderData08 <- read_csv("Downloads/BorderData/BorderApprehension2008.csv")
BorderData07[is.na(BorderData07)] = 0
B08[is.na(B08)] = 0
BorderData07$CITIZENSHIP <- str_to_title(BorderData07$CITIZENSHIP)
BorderData07$Region <- countrycode(sourcevar = BorderData07$CITIZENSHIP, origin = "country.name", destination = "region")
BorderData07[nrow(BorderData07), 26] <- "Total"
World_Region <- ddply(BorderData07,"Region",numcolwise(sum))
ggplot(World_Region, aes(x = Region, y = Total)) + geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(3), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) + scale_y_log10() + coord_flip() +  geom_text(aes(label=Total), alpha = 1.0, check_overlap = TRUE) +  ggtitle("Apprehension By World Region Totals in 2007")
```

I'm trying to use lapply to run through each csv file for every year of my border data. The only difference from each one is the ending of the csv file and the title of the graph. My knowledge of lapply is super limited and am having trouble learning how to get it to function properly.

Comment: Hi, it's really not clear what your question is. You don't seem to have a list so I don't know why lapply makes sense.  Perhaps describe what you are trying to do and provide a minimal example.

Comment: If you're asking how to read those files with `lapply`, I think your question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/6288065. I agree with @Elin; the code that you provide only shows two files (good for a miniminal example), but the other code lines would be irrelevant... Or, are you asking how to run all those codes within `lapply`?.

Comment: @LC-datascientist Ya, sorry I may have not been clear on my question. I am trying to run all those codes within lapply. I only provided two files for an example, but there are 13 files from 2007 to 2019.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse) # a helpful package to make coding easier
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

list.files( # get multiple file paths
    path = "Downloads/BorderData", 
    pattern = "BorderApprehension*.csv", 
    full.names = TRUE
) %>%
    setNames(., paste0("BorderData", str_extract(., "\\d{2}(?=\\.csv)"))) %>% # (optional; provides names to file paths)
    lapply(function(file) {
        year <- str_extract(file, "\\d+(?=\\.csv)") # use in `ggtitle`
        df <- read_csv(file) %>% 
            mutate_all(replace_na, 0) %>% # `BorderData07[is.na(BorderData07)] = 0` equivalent
            mutate(
                CITIZENSHIP = str_to_title(CITIZENSHIP), 
                Region = countrycode(sourcevar = CITIZENSHIP, origin = "country.name", destination = "region")
            )
        df[nrow(df), 26] <- "Total" # BorderData07[nrow(BorderData07), 26] <- "Total"
        World_Region <- ddply(df, "Region", numcolwise(sum))
        ggplot(World_Region, aes(x = Region, y = Total)) + 
            geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(3), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) + 
            scale_y_log10() + 
            coord_flip() + 
            geom_text(aes(label=Total), alpha = 1.0, check_overlap = TRUE) +  
            ggtitle(paste("Apprehension By World Region Totals in", year))
    })
```

The output is a list of ggplots.

If you want it to return the data frames from reading and cleaning the .csv files, you can add a line `return(df)` at the end inside `lapply`.

If you use the optional `setNames` (as shown in the code), the list will have names that correspond to "BorderData07", "BorderData08", etc.

`str_extract(., "\\d{2}(?=\\.csv)")))` in the code's `setNames` uses [regular expressions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) to extract the last two digits before ".csv".

`str_extract(file, "\\d+(?=\\.csv)")))` in the code's `lapply` uses [regular expressions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) to extract one or more digits before ".csv", which would be the year in your example. `(?=\\.csv)` is only needed if you have digits appearing elsewhere in the file path because it indicates that ".csv" has to immediately follow the digits pattern, making the pattern more specific.

The pipe operators (`%>%`) and `mutate` functions are from the `dplyr` R package, which is included in the `tidyverse` package. They help reduce redundant code to write, such as the data frame's name.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything that you want to apply to each file in a function

```
apply_fun <- function(file) {
  x <- read_csv(file)
  year <- str_extract(file, '\\d+')
  x[is.na(x)] = 0
  x$CITIZENSHIP <- str_to_title(x$CITIZENSHIP)
  x$Region <- countrycode(sourcevar = x$CITIZENSHIP, origin = "country.name", destination = "region")
  x[nrow(x), 26] <- "Total"
  World_Region <- ddply(x,"Region",numcolwise(sum))
  ggplot(World_Region, aes(x = Region, y = Total)) + 
    geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(3), fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) + 
    scale_y_log10() + coord_flip() +  
    geom_text(aes(label=Total), alpha = 1.0, check_overlap = TRUE) +  
    ggtitle(paste0("Apprehension By World Region Totals in", year))
}
```

and then use `lapply` -

```
filename <- list.files('Downloads/BorderData/', pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
list_plots <- lapply(filename, apply_fun)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you so much for your help! I understand what you did, I'm just a little confused on what the '//d+' does if you're able to explain!

Comment: `\\d+` is a [regular expression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) that allows a pattern to match one or more of any digits.